# Override model's attribute accessor in a mixin/module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model which includes a module. I'd like to override the model's accessor methods within the module.

For example:

```
class Blah < ActiveRecord::Base
  include GnarlyFeatures
  # database field: name
end

module GnarlyFeatures
  def name=(value)
    write_attribute :name, "Your New Name"
  end
end
```

This obviously doesn't work. Any ideas for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code looks correct. We are using this exact pattern without any trouble.

If I remember right, Rails uses #method_missing for attribute setters, so your module will take precedence, blocking ActiveRecord's setter.

If you are using ActiveSupport::Concern (see [this blog post](http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/09/20/concerning-yourself-with-active-support-concern/), then your instance methods need to go into a special module:

```
class Blah < ActiveRecord::Base
  include GnarlyFeatures
  # database field: name
end

module GnarlyFeatures
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def name=(value)
      write_attribute :name, value
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I must be doing something wrong. How about when you extend ActiveSuppport::Concern as part of the module?

Comment: Awesome! That helped. It wasn't exact, though.In Rails 3.2, it looks like InstanceMethods is no longer included: the deprecation warning simply said to include the accessor in the "included" block.

Comment: Indeed. ActiveSupport::Concern has gone through some changes.

Comment: What is the point of the value arg in the def name= method? Maybe that should be used instead of "Your new Name"

Comment: `ActiveSupport::Concern` in Rails 4 needs you to define `def self.included` instead of the `included do` block. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html